# Matlab: Find duplicated values in column, and sum the values associated with them (in another column)

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

Simple question I guess: I have 2 vectors, one has index numbers from 1 to 10, and the other has just random values.

```
id = [1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7];
val = [.8 .9 .12 .91 .63 .09 .28 .55 .96 .96 ]
```

The results I'm looking for should look like:

```
new_id = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
val = [.8 .9 .12 1.63 .28 .55 1.92]
```

how can I do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[new_id, ~, v] = unique(id(:));
val_summed = accumarray(v, val(:));
```

The above works even if `id` does not necessarily positive integers. If it does, an alternative is to use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to do the sum and [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to extract the desired results:

```
[new_id, ~, val_summed] = find(sparse(id, 1, val));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is called *accumarray*:

```
accumarray(id',val)
```

It calculates the new elements based on the id subscripts.